# MVC 5 ASP.NEt Accessing @model in the middle of img src

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to display images to the screen based on the id passed to the view from the model. I'm new to C#, so I'm not sure if it's possible or what syntax is needed to add variables to my img src.

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/Sprites/@item.pkmnDataId"/>
```

(just assume for now @item.pkmnDataId = 1)

That will not work because it will request ~/Content/Images/Sprites/1
and it needs to request ~/Content/Images/Sprites/1 **.png**

Is it possible to concatenate a '.png' to the img src string (with no space between)?

Thanks!

Comment: `<img src="~/Content/Images/Sprites/@(item.pkmnDataId).png"/>`

Comment: 10 million thank yous my friend!